# Need to use blockly to answer, I will attach the link to the website. Can not use "if" block and equations. Need to use loop. Thank you in advance

Tags: blockly

Design a program to find the total of all integers from 1 to a number specified by the user. The program should ask the user for the number, and then calculate and display the total from 1 to that number. The output message format is ‘The total from 1 to 5 is 15’ where the user enters the number 5, and 15 is the calculated total.

Can only use "Math" "Text" "Logic" "Loops" and "variable"

Website for building:

https://blockly-demo.appspot.com/static/demos/code/index.html

Comment: Please share what you tried and ask a concrete, specific question about your attempt. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i use this site to create the blocks https://developers.google.com/blockly
because i have problem with link you put
but i they have the same future.
[this is the answer  :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VekMc.png)